# can't return file name of dropzone after uploaded codeigniter

Tags: dropzone.js

My controller like this

function uploaded_photo_post(){

```
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; 

    $targetFile = $_FILES['file']['name'];  

    $folder_name_member = self::createFolderMember($this->member_id);

    $targetFile = UPLOAD_DIR . 'members/'. $folder_name_member . '/temps/'. $targetFile;

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //send file to path forder

}
```

My form :

```
<form id="my-awesome-dropzone" method="post" action="/member/uploaded_photo"class="dropzone">
                        <div class="fallback"> <!-- this is the fallback if JS isn't working -->
                            <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

So how can I return path of file name to form. Some time if user don't want to choose that image so I want to send all path name to form. 
Thanks guys